# How to get USC-package-info through php or javascript?

Tags: software-center

Is there a way where I can get information about a package which is in Ubuntu Software Center, such as package-title package-size package-logos etc.
through php or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get packages information you would need to fetch it from the repository and import to your own datasource.

To find the packages indexes which include title's, sisz'es you use:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/release/ # each directory here is a repository section
#
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz # Select the desired arechitcture with binary-i386 or binary-amd64
The file containing the information is:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2

To get the thumbnail for a specific package:

http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/thumbnail/packagename

Comment: Don't forget to set the the question as answered later :)

Comment: But how do I get the logo of a package not the screenshots?

Comment: The icons are available from the app-install-data package, once installed the icons are available on your system at: /usr/share/app-install/icons/ .

Comment: Many thanks.. faster response time than through a normal commercial support page .. really nice João ;)